# Export Html Tables to Multiple Excel Sheet using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to export multiple tables to multiple excel sheet using c#? Below code is working but only for 1 html table.

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelFile.xls");
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
    tbl.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

Below are tables in *.aspx page. And i want to both tables in one excel with multiple sheet.

for Example : Table 1 is in worksheet 1 
 table 2 is in worksheet 2

```
  <table id="tbl" border="1" runat="server" >
                <tr>
                    <td>Product</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Available</td>
                    <td>Count</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bred</td>
                    <td>1
                    </td>
                    <td>2
                    </td>
                    <td>3
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Butter</td>
                    <td>4
                    </td>
                    <td>5
                    </td>
                    <td>6
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

     <table id="tbl2" border="1" runat="server" >
                <tr>
                    <td>KD</td>
                    <td>Dabhi</td>
                    <td>Qnil</td>
                    <td>Dabhi</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bred</td>
                    <td>1
                    </td>
                    <td>2
                    </td>
                    <td>3
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Butter</td>
                    <td>4
                    </td>
                    <td>5
                    </td>
                    <td>6
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>


     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ExportToExcelButton" OnClick="ExportToExcelButton_Click"
        Text="Export To Excel" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example you mentioned, you are `NOT` creating an Excel (or Excel WorkSheets), instead you are trying to open HTML content in Excel format. That is the reason, even if you have `TWO` Tables, they will show up in single sheet.

Use [Microsoft's OpenXml SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30425), through which you can create any number of Sheets and inject data into sheets. Even OpenXml SDK got some minor issues when it comes to Date Type (especially while reading data from Excel sheets). In such a case you can go to any third party Excel automation providers like [SpreadSheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/).

Comment: Thanks,  There is no any other way to solve ? either using C# or other language ?

Comment: Using C#, you can use OpenXml SDK. There is one other way to solve without using OpenXml (or third party tools), that is by constructing you own XML and sending it in response (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/532589/ExportplustoplusExcelplus-e-plusMultipleplus). I dont think this is a generic approach, so I wouldn't suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for GridViews is here:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Exporting-Multiple-GridViews-To-Excel-SpreadSheet-in-ASP.Net.aspx

You may want to look also here for some advise:

[Add table to second sheet of Excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694227/add-table-to-second-sheet-of-excel-using-c-sharp)

You may want to use EPPLUS library (free) instead of interop because it has a lot of functionality:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for your revert. But, I am looking for with HTML Tables not grid-views. :) I really appreciated your efforts here.

Comment: No problem, then using some library like EPPLUS may be a solution for you instead of Interop, it will have more flexibility.

Comment: I have no idea about EPPLUS, Is it possible to convert HTML tables to excel using this library? If yes, How?

Comment: I added the link to it to my post