# Export multiple gridviews to multiple excel tabs (sheets)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have 6 gridviews in my website that I need to export to excel, but each one in one different sheet.

This link [Export GridView to multiple Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632782/export-gridview-to-multiple-excel-sheet) uses something quite similar, but he is using datasets and I am not. I am new to C#, so I couldnt change it to fit my solution.

My code exports all gridviews to the same sheet. I created a loop to run throught my gridviews, now I need to put a code to generate each one to each excel sheet.

```
protected void btExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FARPOP_Mensal_" + txDt.Text + ".xls");
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
    Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView[] gvExcel = new GridView[] { gvAnual, gvPorUF, gvPorFarmacia, gvPorMunicipio, gvPorPV, gvPorCNPJ };
        for (int i = 0; i < gvExcel.Length; i++)
        {
            GridView gv = gvExcel[i];

            // 
            // Need to redirect to each sheet here?
            //

            gvExcel[i].HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
            gvExcel[i].UseAccessibleHeader = false;
            gvExcel[i].AllowPaging = false;
            for (int x = 0; x < gvExcel[i].Columns.Count; x++)
            {
                gvExcel[i].Columns[x].Visible = true;
            }

            gvExcel[i].DataBind();
            foreach (TableCell cell in gvExcel[i].HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                cell.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
                cell.Enabled = false;
            }

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvExcel[i].Rows)
            {
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {

                    cell.Controls.Clear();
                    if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = Color.White;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                    }
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                }
            }

            gvExcel[i].RenderControl(hw);
        }

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you get any further down this rabbit hole, I want to show you Microsoft's recommendations for NOT using Office Automation on the server:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0

You're better off looking for a third-party tool to perform Excel export, or you could have the Excel export run as a scheduled job to be sent to the user later (depending on your needs).

Comment: @maniak1982: the posted code does not use Interop.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @John Saunders: maniak1982 was right. I was using Interop in my previous code. The solution is below.

Comment: Where in your code that you posted did you use Interop? I saw nothing but a GridView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed [maniak1982](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202891/maniak1982) comments and found a good solution.

So, if you need multiple gridviews to multiples worksheets, using .NET, you will need to download [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/releases/view/197852) and also [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll](http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download?ProjectName=closedxml&DownloadId=856114).

After referencing the dll, use the following code:

```
 protected void btExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
    GridView[] gvExcel = new GridView[] { GridView1, GridView2, GridView3, GridView4, GridView5, GridView6};
    string[] name = new string[] { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6" };
    for (int i = 0; i < gvExcel.Length; i++)
    {
        if (gvExcel[i].Visible)
        {
            gvExcel[i].AllowPaging = false;
            gvExcel[i].DataBind();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(name[i].ToString());
            for (int z = 0; z < gvExcel[i].Columns.Count; z++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(gvExcel[i].Columns[z].HeaderText);
            }

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvExcel[i].Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                for (int c = 0; c < row.Cells.Count; c++)
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][c] = row.Cells[c].Text;
                }
            }

            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            gvExcel[i].AllowPaging = true;

        }

    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Workbook_Name.xlsx");
    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

It took me days of searching... But it's working perfectly.
Be happy