# Export multiple gridviews to multiple excel sheets

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have 3 gridviews in my website that I need to export to excel, but i need each gridview to appear in different work sheet.

This link Export GridView to multiple Excel sheet uses something quite similar 
[Export multiple gridviews to multiple excel tabs (sheets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359299/export-multiple-gridviews-to-multiple-excel-tabs-sheets)

For export multiple gridviews to multiples worksheets, I am using .NET and I have downloaded [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/releases/view/197852) and also [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll](http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download?ProjectName=closedxml&DownloadId=856114).

In the web application I don't have error, but the XLS output is empty.

Anybody know how can I resolve this?

Can you suggest any other method?

Thank you in advance.

Please check the code below.

```
protected void btnExportBoth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
    GridView[] gvExcel = new GridView[] { gv1, gv2, gv3 };

    string[] name = new string[] { "gv1", "gv2", "gv3" };

    for (int i = 0; i < gvExcel.Length; i++)
    {
        if (gvExcel[i].Visible)
        {
            gvExcel[i].AllowPaging = false;
            gvExcel[i].DataBind();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable(name[i].ToString());
            for (int z = 0; z < gvExcel[i].Columns.Count; z++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(gvExcel[i].Columns[z].HeaderText);
            }

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvExcel[i].Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                for (int c = 0; c < row.Cells.Count; c++)
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][c] = row.Cells[c].Text;
                }
            }

            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            gvExcel[i].AllowPaging = true;
        }
    }

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Workbook_Name.xlsx");

    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: May be your gridview doesn't contain any data because i can't see you specifying the datasource for gridviews.

Answer (score 1):

You are sure have populated the gridview on `btnExportBoth_Click` method ?

```
        gvExcel[i].AllowPaging = false;
        gvExcel[i].DataBind();
```

In `btnExportBoth_Click` method you must call the method to populate the gridview as on the web.